# Transfer information between two functions in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm creating my first App with React and Firebase and I would like to  transfert data between two functions and save this data into my firebase. But I can not select the good information.

This is my code:

```
import React  from 'react';
import withAuthorization from './withAuthorization';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { config, database, db, auth, itembase, } from 
'../firebase/firebase';


class Catalogue extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
   super();
    this.state = {
    catalogue: []
    };
}

//Item from  Firebase
  componentDidMount() {
  database.on('value', snapshot => {
  this.setState({
    catalogue: snapshot.val()
    });
  });
}

// Add item to user collection
  addToCollection(e) {
    const userUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    const collection = {
    nom: this.state.catalogue[key].nom,
    parution: this.state.catalogue[key].parution
    };

 firebase.database().ref(`users/${userUid}/collection`).push(collection)
}



render(){
  const catalogue= Object.keys(this.state.catalogue).map(key => {
    return (
      <div key={key}>
        <h3>{this.state.catalogue[key].nom}</h3>
        <p>{this.state.catalogue[key].parution}</p>
        <button className="btn btn-success" onClick= 
{this.addToCollection}>Ajouter à ma collection</button> </div>
        )
      });
  return (
    <div>
      {catalogue}
    </div>
  )
 }
}

const authCondition = (authUser) => !!authUser;

export default withAuthorization(authCondition)(Catalogue);
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change couple thing as follow:

```
addToCollection(key, e) {
const userUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
const collection = {
nom: this.state.catalogue[key].nom,
parution: this.state.catalogue[key].parution
};

firebase.database().ref(`users/${userUid}/collection`).push(collection)
};

//then in your render you have to bind your event and key:
render(){
  const catalogue= Object.keys(this.state.catalogue).map(key => {
    return (
      <div key={key}>
        <h3>{this.state.catalogue[key].nom}</h3>
        <p>{this.state.catalogue[key].parution}</p>
    <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.addToCollection.bind(this, key)}>Ajouter à ma collection</button> </div> //change this line.
        )
      });
  return (
    <div>
      {catalogue}
    </div>
  )
 }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you very much Vito Madio !! It's work great !!

Answer (score 0):

You have to render like this:

```
render(){
const catalogues= this.state.catalogue.map(catalogue, key) => { 
return (
     <div key={key}>
     <h3>{catalogue.nom}</h3>        
     <p>{catalogue.parution}</p>
     <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.addToCollection}>Ajouter à ma collection</button> </div>
     ) 
  });

return(
    <div>
    {catalogues}
   </div>
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Hello Vito Madio, thank a lot for your help. I did what you told me but only my button "add to collection" is displayed. I put my whole new code in my first post if you want to see it

Comment: I have succeeded in display data in the page. Now, i can't export data from this object to my function when I click in my button